# How do I create an interface for a contract that has a function parameter type of another contract?

Tags: solidity, interfaces

I'm creating an interface for [SudoSwap's Router](https://github.com/sudoswap/lssvm/blob/main/src/LSSVMRouter.sol)
And the first function requires has a struct parameter

```
function swapETHForAnyNFTs(
        PairSwapAny[] calldata swapList,
        ......
    )...
```

And the struct has a member who's type is another contract, [LSSVMPair.sol](https://github.com/sudoswap/lssvm/blob/main/src/LSSVMPair.sol)

```
struct PairSwapAny {
    LSSVMPair pair;
    uint256 numItems;
}
```

And `LSSVMPair.sol` relies on multiple imports. Am I required to have all of them in my directory to create the interface for the router?

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to declare all functions of the router contract in its interface.

If you don't want to use `swapETHForAnyNFTs` in your main contract, you don't need to import all related contracts to `LSSVMPair.sol`

Comment: ..and if I do want to use `swapETHForAnyNFTs`, then I do need to import everything?

Comment: in that case, you have to import everything